# When to use deep learning for java as opposed to python

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, tensorflow, java

I have been asked to explore options to build deep learning based applications using java, so i happend to browse a website called dl4j (https://deeplearning4j.org) which has got implemantations of different neural networks starting from MLP to RNN/LSTM.

But I couldn't understand the rationale of using dl4j over python based implemenation. So, could someone please clarify on following items please.

1. ETL
2. Data pre-processing
3. Making use of pre-trained models / transfer learning
4. Distributed computing
5. Processing large voulme of data (images,time series data,sensor data..etc)
6. Production implementation (batch or real time / online)
7. Post production training (bacth or real time / online)
8. Mobile app development
9. IoT edge device computing

Comment: I you have to deploy in a Java environment and are unable to use something like docker to simply provide a API with a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to picking a language for a certain application, many factors may play a role:

- Who will be building/maintaining the application and are they familiar with that language?
- What other systems will the application need to communicate with and is one language easier to do that with than the other?
- Is this project experimental or is it supposed to be a cornerstone for the next few years?
- Are there existing implementations/frameworks of what needs to be done in that language? Does it fit the need or does it need to be altered?
- Etc.

If we look at your list, here is my take:

- ETL

ETL is quite a language agnostic, both Java and Python have good bindings to tools necessary for ETL.

- Data pre-processing

Similar to ETL, although Python may be easier to do simple things.

- Making use of pre-trained models / transfer learning

Python is much more convenient as most existing frameworks and pre-trained models are compatible with Python, and likely not with Java.

- Distributed computing

The Hadoop stack is very Java friendly. Good to note that Python is increasingly become easier to use with Hadoop products (but Java is still running underneath)

- Processing large volume of data (images,time series data,sensor data..etc)

Although Python has a reputation of being slow, if you know what you're doing, most Python libraries you'll use will ultimately run C/C++ code anyway, so speed shouldn't be a huge concern.

- Production implementation (batch or real time / online)

Java is statically typed which offers a lot of advantages for production, it's becoming steadily easier to do this with Python as well (i.e. pydantic, mypy, etc.)

- Post production training (bacth or real time / online)

This is independent of the language, this has more to do with your MLOps and your pipelines in place.

- Mobile app development

Java definitely has the edge, although in a world of microservices, Python can prove very helpful.

- IoT edge device computing

When it comes to device computing, Java probably has the edge, although, C/C++ are likely your best allies.